# event.preventDefault() with Angularjs and UIRouter removes browser history

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am showing a Javascript `Confirm` prompt when users click on a browser `Back` button by watching the `$stateChangeStart` event.  Consider the following:

Users navigate from page 1, 2, then page 3.  On page 3, user clicks the `Back` button, they get presented with a Confirm box.  User clicks on the `Cancel` button, `event.preventDefault()` is executed and the user remains on the same page.  Then if the user clicks `Back` again, and chooses `OK` the second time, the user is taken back to page 1.  What happened to page 2? Does `event.preventDefault()` remove the last history?  How do I prevent the browser from skipping the previous page?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var retVal = confirm("You have unsaved changes. If you leave the page, these changes will be lost.");
        if (retVal == false) {
            // user wants to cancel navigating back. 
            event.preventDefault();         
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep history while preventing Back button click you have to do that watching **$locationChangeStart** event instead of **$stateChangeStart**.

This is because $stateChangeStart in contrast to $locationChangeStart is broadcased after the transition has been executed and browser history is already updated.

So it should go like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next) {
    var retVal = confirm("You have unsaved changes. If you leave the page, these changes will be lost.");
    if (retVal == false) {
        // user wants to cancel navigating back. 
        event.preventDefault();         
    }
});
```